# How do I stop 2 stray cats that fight

Tags: cats, aggression, desexing

I have adopted 1 stray  cat that fights with another stray cat. I would like to adopt the other stray cat, would that be possible? the cats are both toms and have not been neutered. Is there any chance of them stopping fighting

Comment: Are you planning to neuter them?

Comment: Intend to get them neutered as soon as possible but not sure that will stop them fighting. One of the cats is at vets at moment from fighting and would like to bring him back to live with me

Comment: Unneutered males will fight over females, you won't have this problem with a neutered male. I'd recommend neutering ASAP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop two male cats from fighting](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/how-to-stop-two-male-cats-from-fighting)

Comment: Also related: [How should I react to two fighting cats](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-should-i-react-to-two-fighting-cats)

Comment: @GimmeTehRepz the question you list as a possible duplicate is about non-recognition aggression, which is a different situation than 2 unneutered males who don't know each other.

Comment: @Zaralynda Hmm.. Yeah that might be the wrong Q&A to have linked. But I do think it's been answered before.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will probably work out fine. Once they are both neutered, it will be much easier to get them to stop fighting. I recommend you get them neutered at the same time, and as soon as possible. When you are not around to supervise them, keep them separated until you are sure they are getting along. There may be a bit of yowling and posturing at first, but things should settle down quickly.

I don't think the fighting will persist, but if it lasts longer than you expect, ask for help again. These problems can usually be sorted without much difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

Try to neuter your cat.  The best way to stop a cat fight is to spray water to break up the fight.

[Jackson Galaxy has more tips on resolving this here](http://jacksongalaxy.com/2012/06/23/qa-how-to-stop-cats-from-fighting/).